# YouTube videos won't play in Safari (iPod Gen 3 / iOS 5.1.1)

Tags: ios, safari, ipod-touch, youtube

When I try to play a YouTube video I just see the following message:

> This operation could not be completed.

I've tried restarting my internet, resetting my iPod, HARD Resetting my iPod, and deleting some apps.

My iPod has 28 GB of memory left, so I know I'm not running out of memory. It's really frustrating to think that Apple might have disabled video playing in safari for iOS 5.1! Please help me, I cannot stand another day without my YouTube!

Device: iPod touch 3rd Gen, 2009 (iPod3,1)

OS: iOS 5.1.1